# PHP проверка форм

Tags: php

*Стандартное вступление*:
Только начинаю изучать php, не ругайтесь за глупый вопрос и т.д.
Код из книги Робина Никсона.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = $_POST['name'];
else $name = '(Не введено)';
echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Вас зовут $name<br />
    <form method = 'post' action = 'count.php'>
        Как вас зовут?
        <input type='text' name='name' />
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
_END
?>
```

**Вопрос:** Во *второй* строке с помощью *isset()* проверяем установлена переменная или нет. В третьей у нас условие: если не установлена, то выводим "(Не введено)". Вот что не пойму: открываю страницу - выводит:

> Вас зовут (Не введено)
> Как вас зовут? (и форма для отправки)

Ничего не ввожу, нажимаю "отправить" - выводит:

> Вас зовут 
> Как вас зовут? **(и НЕ выводит "не введено")** (и форма для отправки)

То есть, я ничего не ввожу, но функция, считает, что переменная была установлена значением отличным от **NULL**. Почему?
Если она пропускает пустое значение, то зачем ее использовать? Почему не использовать *empty*? Но во всех программах вижу именно такую проверку. Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей `empty` не обязательно *существующую* проверяет, она вполне нормально работает и с undefined (выдет NULL). 

    if (isset($a) and !empty($a)) // тавтология, if A and (A and B)

Здесь достаточно `!empty`.

Алсо, в этот вопрос надо тыкать мордой многих новеньких, ибо он хоть и нубский, но хорошо оформлен и адекватно задан, посему плюсану)

Comment: @Sh4dow, да заглянул в документацию, действительно `empty` работает и на несуществующие переменные. Век живи - век учись. Но мой скептизм всяко хочет отрицать такую работу `empty`.. =)

Comment: Если рассуждать логически, то какая перед нами стоит задача? Задача состоит в том, чтобы узнать, производилась ли отправка данных. Именно поэтому используется `isset()`. А то, что данные пришли пустыми - ну что же, бывает и такое. В этом случае мы сможем вывести пользователю некое информационное сообщение, мол "поле такое-то обязательно для заполнение". А с `empty()` мы понятия не имеем, что именно произошло, а значит не сможем правильно среагировать.

З.Ы. если задача из учебника вызвала кучу вопросов - значит свое дело она сделала...)

Comment: @Равнодушный вообще в таких случаях принято отправлять еще hidden-поле)

    $action = !empty($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
    if ($action == 'save') {
      // а тут isset чаще всего просто не нужен, т.к. 
      // набор полей известен
    }

Но это уже другая история)

И да, @Яковлев Андрей, тут тема глубже на самом деле. `empty` принимает ссылку, а пустая ссылка не выдает `warning`'и, а просто содержит NULL. Довольно неочевидная фича, но ее можно пользовать. На закуску:

    $a = null; var_dump(isset($a)); // bool (false)

Answer (score 11):

Да, после сабмита $_POST['name'] получил право на существование (`isset`).
Ведь пустая строка - тоже значение.
А если есть значение, то есть и переменная.
Но вы верно подметили почему бы не взять `empty`?
А разница в том, что empty проверяет на пустоту значения **существующей** переменной.
Поэтому тут оптимальным будет двойное условие:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))
```

Comment: очень долго к каждой переменной писать это, используйте foreach для всего массива post или get а также trim'те и !empty'те любое $value имеющего ся в массиве ключа ($key)

Answer (score 2):

```
if( strlen($_POST['name'])>2 ){

    //если длина $_POST['name'] больше 2 выполняется тут

}
```

Comment: @Дима Гребиняк, круто. А я возьму и поставлю 2 пробела.

Comment: Если передали массив, а если кодировка левая?

Answer (score 2):

Может мой ответ покажется глупым, но:

1. У меня лично есть привычка ещё с университета - обрамлять операторы, выполняющиеся в конструкции "`if-then-else`" в блоки. В данном случае, "{" и "}".
2. При изучении `PHP4`, у меня возникала иногда проблема с переменными, которая решалась настройками файлов конфигурации: `php.ini` или `httpd.conf`.

Думаю, в п.2 больше вероятности решения проблемы.
Удачи!

P.S.: Оператор "@" ещё никто не отменял. Насколько я помню, он нужен для того, чтобы предотвратить ошибки при первичной инициализации переменной.
Как-то так.

Comment: Плохая привычка:

      У меня лично есть привычка ещё с университета - обрамлять операторы, выполняющиеся в конструкции "if-then-else" в блоки. В данном случае, "{" и "}".

Comment: Оператор "@" тут не имеет отношения к вопросу. Он просто скрывает показ ошибок и нотисов. Это "плохой" оператор. Даже для своего проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Есть же документация. [Таблица сравнения типов в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
// переменные которые ждёте:
$name = "(не введено)";
$age = "(не указано)";

// получаем из пост
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $clear_val = trim ($value); // тут может быть: html_spec_char, sql_spec_char итд
    if (!empty($clear_val)) {
        $$key = $clear_val;
    }
}

print "Имя: $name, возраст $age.";
```